# HTTP calls missing from Application Flow Map after JDK Upgrade

Tags: controller, installation, jvm, microsoft-dynamics, javaagents

We have one application (App A) which calls another app (App B) via HTTP(s) API. Both apps have AppD Machine and App agents installed. After performing an upgrade on App A from Java 1.8 to OpenJDK11, we are no longer seeing the interaction between App A & B on the Application Flow Map.

Any idea why an HTTP API call would no longer show up on our Application Flow Map after a JDK upgrade? We know for certain the call is still being made, otherwise there'd be a much larger fire to put out.
Agent version is 4.5.4

```
 App A is custom Java app running on OpenJDK11
 This is what has changed
 App B is a COTS Java app running on Java 1.8
 App A connects to App B via HTTP(s) API call
 Both App A and App B have machine agents installed and running
 Both are running on Java 1.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install agent version 4.5.6 or above